# Bibliography changes style after entry 15

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am writing a MSc. thesis and am writing it up in LaTex. I make use of `natbib` and am happy with how it generates a nice bibliography, but I am running into an issue where the format of the beginning of the bibliography changes after entry 15 to more of a blocky font.

Is this an issue with my usage of the `natbib` package?

```
% In Settings.tex
\usepackage{natbib}

% In References.tex
\setcitestyle{numbers}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{lit}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% In main.tex, have already included settings.tex
% REFERENCES / BIBLIOGRAPHY 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\begin{flushleft} 
\footnotesize 
\input{include/backmatter/References} 
\end{flushleft}
```

The respective .bib entries for 15 and 16:

```
@Misc{Giusca2005,
  author  = {Bogdan Giuşcă},
  title   = {The problem of the Seven Bridges of Königsberg.},
  year    = {2005},
  note    = {File: \ttfamily{Konigsberg bridges.png}},
  url     = {https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Konigsberg_bridges.png},
  urlseen = {12-04-19},
}

@Article{Goldford2018,
  author    = {Goldford, Joshua E. and Lu, Nanxi and Baji{\'c}, Djordje and Estrela, Sylvie and Tikhonov, Mikhail and Sanchez-Gorostiaga, Alicia and Segr{\`e}, Daniel and Mehta, Pankaj and Sanchez, Alvaro},
  title     = {Emergent simplicity in microbial community assembly},
  journal   = {Science},
  year      = {2018},
  volume    = {361},
  number    = {6401},
  pages     = {469--474},
  issn      = {0036-8075},
  doi       = {10.1126/science.aat1168},
  eprint    = {http://science.sciencemag.org/content/361/6401/469.full.pdf},
  publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science},
  url       = {http://science.sciencemag.org/content/361/6401/469},
}
```

[image: The bibliography style changes after entry 15, no matter how many additional sources I add]

**EDIT:**
Making some compilable .tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{msc}
\author{rosko }
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\citep{Giusca2005} did this
\citep{Goldford2018} did that

% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

But with just these, the output has similar style:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The problem is probably in the `.bib` file entry for item 15. Can you edit your question and add that `.bib` item and make your code compilable.

Comment: My guess would be that whatever typesets the "File: `Konigsberg bridges.png.`" has a leaking font definition (something like `File: \ttfamily Konigsberg bridges.png.` instead of `File: {\ttfamily Konigsberg bridges.png}.`). My money would be on the contents of the `.bib` file (maybe the `note` field?). But it could also be a bad BibTeX style.

Comment: Aha! Indeed: `note = {File: \ttfamily{Konigsberg bridges.png}},` is wrong. Write either `note = {File: \texttt{Konigsberg bridges.png}},` (I would prefer this) or `note = {File: {\ttfamily Konigsberg bridges.png}},`. `\ttfamily` is a switch that changes the font until the end of the current group. It is not a macro that takes an argument. `\texttt` on the other hand is a macro with a normal argument.

Comment: Problem resolved, \ttfamily was the issue. Will vote that as the solution if you add it, and will edit post to include the resolution.

Comment: No need to edit your post with a solution. @moewe can turn his comment into an answer and you can accept it by clicking the checkmark icon beside it once its posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many font operations LaTeX knows two types of commands: *Font switches* and *text macros*. Font switches apply from the point they are written until the end of the current group. They do *not* take an argument. Text macros take an argument and generally only apply the formatting to that argument. Usually the name of the text macro includes begins with `\text...`.

That implies that normally switches are used as

```
Unaffected text {\<switch> affected text} more unaffected text
```

and text macros as

```
Unaffected text \<text macro>{affected text} more unaffected text
```

For example `\bfseries` is a switch

```
normal text {\bfseries bold text} more normal text
```

and `\textbf` is the corresponding text macro

```
normal text \textbf{bold text} more normal text
```

You can read more about those commands at [Braces inside or outside?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/367882/35864), [How to apply formatting (sans-serif, color etc.) to multiple paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97692/35864), [\bfseries is to \textbf as WHAT is to \textsf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7669/35864). In general there is no way you can know beforehand what the argument structure of a command is, i.e. if it is a switch or a text macro. You have to look it up or experiment. The only 'rule' is that many (if not all) text macros start with `\text...`. Many font switches end in `\...series`, `\...font`, `\...shape`, `\...size`.

---

`\ttfamily` is a font switch. Its effect persist until the current group is closed. When the note field contains

```
note    = {File: \ttfamily{Konigsberg bridges.png}},
```

then the effect of `\ttfamily` doesn't end at the `}` after `.png`. Instead it persists until the current group is ended. In the example that is only at the very end of the bibliography.

Instead of `\ttfamily` you want to use `\texttt`. That command takes and argument and typesets it in typewriter font.

```
note    = {File: \texttt{Konigsberg bridges.png}},
```

Alternatively, you could restrict `\ttfamily` with proper grouping

```
note    = {File: {\ttfamily Konigsberg bridges.png}},
```

Comment: +1 How to turn a simple problem into a really useful answer!